# Shopware 6 - add new Promotion invalidation condition next to Max total uses and Max uses per customer

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopware, shopware6

I try to add a MaxBudget functionality to the Shopware 6 promotions. This field is supposed to work like the fields Max total uses (MaxRedemptionsGlobal) and Max uses per customer (MaxRedemptionsPerCustomer).

*This means that if the promotion has a budget of say... 1000 euros, when the discount from this promotion for all orders adds up to 1000 euros the promotion is invalid. Just like when Max total uses threshold is reached.*

I added MaxBudget as an entity extension and have a field for it under Max. uses per customer in administration.

As for the storefront cart I noticed the conditions for Max uses (global and per customer) and checked in PromotionCollector. In the `private function getEligiblePromotionsWithDiscounts` there is this code validating the order max uses per customer and order max uses global:

```
if (!$promotion->isOrderCountValid()) {
    continue;
}

if ($customer !== null && !$promotion->isOrderCountPerCustomerCountValid($customer->getId())) {
    continue;
}
```

What I need is, right after the conditions above to add an additional condition like the following:

```
if ($promotion->getMaxBudget()->maxBudgetReached()) {
    continue;
}
```

**So the question would be, where can I add an additional condition besides these two, to check the max budget ? Do I have to extend the PromotionCollector class and override the method ? Maybe I can add a new class like PromotionMaxBudgetCollector. I am not sure if this is the right approach.**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are facing is that [`\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Promotion\Cart\PromotionCollector::getEligiblePromotionsWithDiscounts`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/a81c91cfe90c2c0eb6ba912dcb6603d5d54d5f89/src/Core/Checkout/Promotion/Cart/PromotionCollector.php#L284) is private and cannot be decorated to add a new condition.

You could [decorate](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/adjusting-service#decorating-the-service) [`\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Promotion\PromotionEntity::hasDiscount`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/a81c91cfe90c2c0eb6ba912dcb6603d5d54d5f89/src/Core/Checkout/Promotion/PromotionEntity.php#L608) or [`\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Promotion\PromotionEntity::isOrderCountValid`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/a81c91cfe90c2c0eb6ba912dcb6603d5d54d5f89/src/Core/Checkout/Promotion/PromotionEntity.php#L613) and return `false`, if your condition is not met.

Comment: Hi Alex. My only concern with decorating in Shopware is that I saw decorating something completely overrides it. Like for example I override a route.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can access the original method when decorating something - ut maybe there is a better solution to this.

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try and come back. As for the override, I did not know you can still use the original function, because it is not like a php class inheritance, where you can call parent::functionName(). Are you sure this is possible ? I did not find it in documentation either

Comment: What I mean is that you can call the public method of the inner / decorated service: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/adjusting-service#decorating-the-service